# how can I transform a bootstrap horizontal form to a vertical form?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to get a horizontal input or form to become vertical when it's on mobile (with bootstrap). I found an answer here but it doesn't work, maybe it's outdated.

The original bootstrap code was modified so the input would be on the right side of the screen. When I tried the answer found here from years ago it didn't work at all and also modified the original result on desktop. Should I use form tag as well? I'm not even sure... I'm desperate please help...

```
<div class="row mx-1">
  <div class="col-lg-4 float-left">
    <h5>Recevez nos offres ou annonces</h5>
  </div>

<div class="input-group col-lg-6 float-right">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary dropdown-toggle" 
 type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria- 
   expanded="false">Vous êtes</button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Consultant</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Partenaire</a>
  </div>
</div>
  <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg col-xs-12" 
  aria-label="Text input with dropdown button" placeholder="E-mail">
  <div class="input-group-append">
    <button method="POST" class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn- 
subscribe btn-lg" type="button">Souscrire</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

the code I sent is the result I want for desktop. For mobile ideally they'd have to be centered, one on top of the other without any margins.

Answer (score 0):

from looking at your code you are not using col-md col-sm and col-xs for smaller screen

col-lg is use for only large screen

col-md for medium size screen

col-sm for tablet size screen

col-xs for mobiles

you can use col-xs-4 with col-lg-4

and col-xs-6 with col-lg-6

Comment: thanks I will try that. The issue is that I had to add some css because the facebook and linkedin logos have a border. It was such a hassle to make it cause they are seperate elements that in the end reult have to be next to each other with no radius on one side. Everytime I tried to add different col and sm it disturbed the borders. I also had tried to put them in a div (both a elements) and it didn't work either :(

Comment: can you provide the image or html with css